# The Earth Mover's Distance/ Wasserstein metric between 2 histograms (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, distance

I want to measure the distance between two histograms using The Earth Mover's Distance, also called  Wasserstein metric. I extract the histograms from images.

This is how I extract the histogram from my image:

```
[N1,X1]=hist(image1,128)
[N2,X2]=hist(image2,128)
```

128 represent the number of class in the histograms.

so i found the code here: https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22962-the-earth-mover-s-distance?focused=5110777&tab=function

```
function [x, fval] = emd(F1, F2, W1, W2, Func)
% EMD   Earth Mover's Distance between two signatures
%    [X, FVAL] = EMD(F1, F2, W1, W2, FUNC) is the Earth Mover's Distance
%    between two signatures S1 = {F1, W1} and S2 = {F2, W2}. 
%    F1 and F2 consists of feature vectors which describe S1 and S2, respectively. 
%    Weights of these features are stored in W1 and W2. 
%    FUNC is a function which computes the ground distance between two feature vectors.
```

But I don't really see how I can apply that in my case. Indeed, in my case what is F1 et F2 ? and what is the weights?!

Thank you!

Comment: This is a rather mathematical question about EMD than a programming one. The question is not specific to the mentioned implementation. Consider asking it at https://math.stackexchange.com/ (and delete it here).

Answer (score 1):

The features are going to be the different characteristics of the probability for the probability metric you are looking at. If you consider a color of the eyes of a set of people, one feature could be the "blue" characteristic. The weight will be the number of people with that particular characteristic. I hope that this makes sense!

I'm not personally a Matlab sort of person, however [this](https://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/KantorovichWithJulia.html) is good blog post which shows how it's possible to calculate this distance in Julia.

A relevant question in maths stack overflow [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656525/kantorovich-distance-discrete-distributions/1661561)

[Wiki link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric)